# Boostrap form validation mutiple forms on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, bootstrap-4

I'm working on form validation here I have three modal popups inside these three forms and validation working fine. But the problem is success message not coming to the last two forms only working with the first form. what might be the issue here last form success message not coming. Can anyone suggest me the right direction what I'm missing here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^='formVal_']").bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
      valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
      $('#success_message').css('display', 'flex').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();

      var bv = form.data('bootstrapValidator');
      // Use Ajax to submit form data
      $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(result) {}, 'json');
      $("[id^='formVal_']").bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);
    },
    fields: {
      name: {
        validators: {
          nameMessage: {
            message: 'Please supply a valid name'
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply your name'
          }
        }
      },
      email: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply your email address'
          },
          emailAddress: {
            message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
          }
        }
      }

    }
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="modal fade" id="oneModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="oneModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="formVal_test1">

          <!-- Text input-->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input name="name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <!-- Success message -->
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>

          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Second form -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="twoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="twoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="formVal_test2">

          <!-- Text input-->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input name="name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <!-- Success message -->
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>

          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Third form -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="threeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="threeModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="formVal_test3">

          <!-- Text input-->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input name="name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <!-- Success message -->
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>

          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#oneModal">First</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#twoModal">Second</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#threeModal">Third</a>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id `success_message`. An id is supposed to identify a unique element in your page.

Comment: @sim0ne yes exactly thanks. I missed that point :)